# How to search for a sub string within a string using Pyspark

Tags: string, substring, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The image added contains sample of [image: an input and desired output].

For example, if sentence contains "John" and "drives" it means John has a car and to get to work he drives. I'm attaching code I'm using to do it. However, the code doesn't work correctly and is too complicated. I will appreciate your help.

```
%pyspark
rdd = sc.textFile("./sample.txt")
col = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split('\t'))
#remove header
header = col.first() #extract header
col = col.filter(lambda line: line != header)
def convertToRow(line):
    return Row(Name = line[0],Text = line[1])
#call the function on each row, then convert to dataframe    
df = col.map(convertToRow).toDF()
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def splitParagraphIntoSentences(paragraph):
    sentences = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(paragraph)
    return sentences

def tokenize(text):
    text = text.lower().replace('\n', '')
    text = re.sub(',', '', text)
    tokens = text.split()
    if(len(tokens)>1):
        tokens = splitParagraphIntoSentences(text)
    return tokens

tokenize = udf(lambda text: tokenize(text))
data = df.select('Name', tokenize(df.Text).alias("Text"))
def how(name,paragraph):
    drive = ['drives']
    walks = ['walks']
    comingwith = ['coming with']  
    for s in paragraph:
        s = s.split()
        if ((any(s[i:i+len(drive)]==drive for i in xrange(len(s)-len(drive)+1))) and (any(s[i:i+len(name)]==name for i in xrange(len(s)-len(name)+1)))):
            return "Drives"
        elif ((any(s[i:i+len(walks)]==walks for i in xrange(len(s)-len(walks)+1))) and (any(s[i:i+len(name)]==name for i in xrange(len(s)-len(name)+1)))):
            return "Walks"
        elif ((any(s[i:i+len(comingwith)]==comingwith for i in xrange(len(s)-len(comingwith)+1))) and (any(s[i:i+len(name)]==name for i in xrange(len(s)-len(name)+1)))):
            return "Coming with" 

def checkYesNo(name,paragraph):
    drive = ['drives']
    walks = ['walks']
    comingwith = ['coming with']  
    for s in paragraph:
        s = s.split()
        if ((any(s[i:i+len(comingwith)]==comingwith for i in xrange(len(s)-len(comingwith)+1))) or (any(s[i:i+len(walks)]==walks for i in xrange(len(s)-len(walks)+1)))):
            return "No"  
        else: 
            return "Yes"

how = udf(lambda name,paragraph: how(name,paragraph))
checkYesNo = udf(lambda name,paragraph: checkYesNo(name,paragraph))

final_df = data.select('Name', checkYesNo(data.Name, data.Text), how(data.Name, data.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
import socket

class SparkUtil(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_spark_context (host, venv, framework_name, parts):
        os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "{0}/bin/python".format (venv)
        from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
        from StringIO import StringIO
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        sparkConf = (SparkConf()
                     .setMaster(host)
                     .setAppName(framework_name))
        return SparkContext(conf = sparkConf)

input_txt = [
    [ "John", "John usually drives to work. He usually gets up early and drinks coffee. Mary usually joining him." ],
    [ "Sam",  "As opposed to John, Sam doesn't like to drive. Sam usually walks there." ],
    [ "Mary", "Mary doesn't have driving license. Mary usually coming with John which picks her up from home." ]
]

def has_car (text):
    return "drives" in text

def get_method (text):
    method = None
    for m in [ "drives", "walks", "coming with" ]:
        if m in text:
            method = m
            break
    return method

def process_row (row):
    return [ row[0], has_car(row[1]), get_method(row[1]) ]

sc = SparkUtil.get_spark_context (host           = "local[2]",
                                  venv           = "../starshome/venv",
                                  framework_name = "app",
                                  parts          = 2)

print (sc.parallelize (input_txt).map (process_row).collect ())
```

The SparkUtil class you can probably ignore. I'm not using a notebook. This is just a straight up Spark app.